# Why can StreamRecords be optional in Amazon DynamoDB streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Glossing at the documentation for DynamoDB Streams, I encountered that the dynamodb object is optional

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Record.html

This seems intuitively to me like something that should always be defined and included? In which cases can I assume that it will be undefined?

Comment: Where do you see it as being optional?

Comment: In Typescript the field Dynamodb is optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamodb` will always be present. You are looking at API documentation, which states what parameters are required by you. As this is a read only object, none of the items listed are required.

Contrast that with [`Get`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Get.html) and you will see that `key` is required as you must pass `key` parameter in the request.